# How to load mobiscroll values from server

Tags: asp.net, mobiscroll

I'm using the select preset option of the mobiscroll control and i'd like to load its values from the server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Mobiscroll is a client side controll. If you would like to use the select preset with the values you have on server side, you should create a html select element and then on client side initiate the mobiscroll with that element.

```
<select name="City" id="select" style="display:none">
    <!-- the options from you -->
    <option value="value1">Option1</option>
    <option value="value2">Option2</option>
    ...
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#select').scroller({
        preset: 'select'
    });
});
</script>
```